# ORM Framework to avoid UPDATE operation on specific fields

Tags: hibernate, orm

Is there any ORM framework (preferably in hibernate) that can provide facility to avoid UPDATE operation on certain fields through annotations or any other means. Let me elaborate with an example.

Customer : CustomerId, Name, CurrentAddressId, PermanentAddressId etc...
Address : AddressId, AddressLine1, AddressLine2 etc...

Let us say that there is a form being filled / updated by Customer to provide all his details along with Current & Permanent Address. While filling / updating the form and submitting, using any of the http request interception tools, it is possible for end user to change the CurrentAddressId, PermanentAddressId already associated with him while updating the customer profile. Hence, while doing the UPDATE operation on Customer profile, I wanted to restrict update operation on CurrentAddressId, PermanentAddressId fields for customer (table / hibernate entity). Is it possible to achieve it through any of the ORM frameworks through annotations / any other means.

Comment: you can use hibernate and set updatable attribute to false for any column that you want. for example @Column(name="createdDate",updatable=false) private Date createdDate=new Date();

Comment: Thanks alizadeh. May I know if there is any such provision in mybatis too, like Typehandlers used for type conversions, is there any way in mybatis which gives us old and new values just before executing UPDATE statement so that we can write business logic there?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have any experience in mybtis